# ABP Cannot connect redis cache

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have problem when switch cache from in memory to redis cache, in CoreModule I write code like this :

[image]

When I start Web.Host, an error like this :

[image]

Did I miss something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check whether your module depends on `AbpRedisCacheModule`.

```cs
 [DependsOn(
        //...other module dependencies
        typeof(AbpRedisCacheModule))]
    public class MyProjectWebModule : AbpModule
```

---

Also you can check [that](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4395) issue.

Comment: Issue has been solved, any wrong configuration on my redis server on docker.